# Static ip address for outgoing (i.e out of azure) traffic from a service hosted in service fabric?

Tags: configuration, azure-service-fabric, static-ip-address

I have a need to communicate from services (hosted in azure service fabric) to communicate with our on-premises resources. I would like all outgoing traffic from azure to have a static ip address so that on-premises network team can create a firewall incoming firewall rule based on this static ip address.

Since the service(s) hosted in service fabric can move from node to node (without user's intervention) and auto-scale feature can add new nodes or tear down existing nodes, I am guessing I have to use something with configuration step. So I would like to know following:

1) What needs to be modified in the fabric cluster so that all outgoing traffic has static ip address?
2) How do I modify it at configuration step so that I don't worry about node to node switch as well as auto-scale feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All nodes get the same outbound IP address, the same public IP that is assigned to your cluster/load balances in Azure. You can specify the public IP address by using an ARM template to deploy your cluster, you specify a name of the public IP (and that public IP is assigned to your subscription and is then referenced in the ARM template for the cluster).

Comment: So can I configure cluster IP address static and custom?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it will be assigned when you build the cluster, I don't think you can choose the address, but it is static, i.e. as long as your cluster is alive the address never changes.

Comment: That does not help if we can not set a static ip address. That creates a huge headache to on-premise customers. Hope some one knows how to do this properly.

Comment: It's static, it doesn't change. So you can definitely use this for firewall rules.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not make that clear. I need the ip address to persist across multiple tear down and spinning up of service fabric cluster each time. I want the ability to set the ip address during spinning up of service fabric cluster. I will make sure that there is only one cluster with that ip address at any given time. Can I do that?

Comment: Ah I understand. Yes, you can do that by using an ARM template to deploy your cluster, you specify a name of the public IP (the public IP is assigned to your subscription and is then referenced in the ARM template for the cluster). I assume you're aware that it's not a typical scenario to spin up/down clusters, typically you leave the cluster running and then you deploy packages to it as needed.